# In React , same content is showing on another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In Home.js ,

```
render(){
Return <BrowserRouter>
<AppBar>
<ToolBar>
<Button component={Link} to={"/profile"}>Profile</Button>
</ToolBar></AppBar>
<Switch>
<Route path="/profile" render={props=><Profile {...props} user={user}/>}></Route>
</Switch>
<div>hello!!!!</div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

My problem is this hello!!! content showing on Profile page as well.

So how to solve this?

Comment: Routers render all children. Put the hello div outside the router or place on a `Route` with a specific path. Use a `Switch` within the `Router` if you want to further what matches and renders. The react-router-dom [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) are also very helpful.

Comment: I have tried with Switch tag as well but didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The content of this component will contain everything in the children, therefore conditionally everything in the Route's render method assuming it matches the path.

Use a switch to ensure only one route is matched.

```
<Router>
<div>Static header on all pages/routes</div>
<Switch>          
    <Route path="/profile" render={props=><Profile {...props} user={user}/>}></Route>
    <Route path="/anotherpage" render={props=><div>hello!!!!</div>}></Route>
</Switch>
<div>Static footer on all pages/routes</div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added {return hello!!!}}/>

It works now.